# Why am I getting the error "'request' is not defined"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, spotify

I'm trying to create an app with the Spotify API, but can't seem to get it to work. The error I'm getting is that 'request' is undefined and I've replaced it with JQuery too and that doesn't work either. Can anyone tell me why I might be getting that error and how to fix it? Should I be running it inside node.js in cmd?

```
var client_id = '?';
var client_secret = '?';

var authOptions = {
  url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64'))
  },
  form: {
    grant_type: 'client_credentials'
  },
  json: true
};

request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
    var token = body.access_token;
  }
  else {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
}
});
```

Comment: `request` looks a bit like it would be from the `request` npm package. Are you importing/requiring it?

Comment: You can't run this code in a browser.

Comment: @Evert no, to install it would it just be npm install request?

Comment: @robertklep why can't this be run within a browser?

Comment: @Evert I just installed it but request is still not defined

Comment: It's code designed for use with `node.js`. If you install a package with `npm`, it is installed for use with `node.js`, not for your `javascript` engine inside your browser.

Comment: @AidanAUS as said, `request` depends on Node.js. You can run [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) from a browser, but then the question becomes if the Spotify API will actually allow you to make that request from a browser, and I'm fairly certain it won't.

Comment: @mime oh, so what can I do? I got the code from: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/client-credentials/

Comment: @robertklep where should I be running it then?

Comment: @AidanAUS if you're in a browser, use `fetch` instead of `request`. it's built in.

Comment: 1. Run it with `node.js` from your `cli`. 2. `request` is [deprectated](https://github.com/request/request/blob/master/README.md), so see the [Node.js Documentation](https://nodejs.dev/learn/making-http-requests-with-nodejs) instead on how to make a HTTP-Post Request

Comment: @Evert Do you mean just change the word 'request' or actually change the whole section of code.

Comment: @Mime How would I then rewrite the request to make it adhere to Node.js Documentation and the Axios library? I'm not too sure how that works

Comment: Also why wouldn't this be mentioned on Spotify's website where they share the code? Could you explain why what they have on their website doesn't work for me?

Comment: I assume that they simply don't update the documentation that often, as the API is more of a nice to have feature instead of their main business. But i and probably no one other than the people working there can really tell.

Comment: I posted an answer which makes a basic request to the server with no external libraries. But please, work through the [Node.js Basics](https://nodejs.dev/learn), as it seems that you are lacking knowledge on the framework in general. Also, make sure you understand the code i posted before using it, as this will help you more in solving further problems then simply copy pasting it.

Comment: @AidanAUS no it's not enough to change the keyword, learn how the `fetch` library works. And just to repeat, use `fetch` in browsers or Node 18. If you're on an older Node them @Mime's answer may be better.

Answer (score 0):

The spotify documentation is out of date, as `request` is [deprecated](https://github.com/request/request/blob/master/README.md), and should no longer be used.
Instead, you can make a request with built-in Node.js libraries, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://nodejs.dev/learn/making-http-requests-with-nodejs).

It should be run with `node.js`, i.e. `node <filename>`

```
const https = require('https')

const client_id = 'CLIENT_ID'
const client_secret = 'CLIENT_SECRET'

const reqBody = JSON.stringify({
  grant_type: 'client_credentials'
})

const authOptions = {
  hostname: 'accounts.spotify.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/api/token',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer.from(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64')),
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': reqBody.length
  }
}

const req = https.request(authOptions, res => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

  res.on('data', d => {
    process.stdout.write(d)
  })
})

req.write(reqBody);
req.end();
```